# PHP form updating process isn't work as expected

Tags: php, html

I've created a HTML form and I want let the user to update his/her data. All the insert and delete functions are working well, but update function returns an error saying, 
"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE regNumber = 'IT17456734'' at line 1." Whatever the registration number I enter, it doesn't let me to edit existing data. Could anyone please spot out the error? As I'm a beginner  at PHP, I can't go further. Here's my PHP Code.

```
<?php
require 'db_connect.php';
```

?>

Comments On Library Services

```
<div align = "center">

<h4>

<?php   

    if(!empty($_POST["regNo"]) && !empty($_POST["fullname"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"]) && !empty($_POST["faculty"]) && !empty($_POST["year"]))
    {
        $regNumber = $_POST["regNo"];
        $name = $_POST["fullname"];
        $comment = $_POST["comment"];
        $year = $_POST["year"];
        $faculty = $_POST["faculty"];

        //echo "Successfully values collected from form.html";
    }   

    else
    {
        $error = "One or more fields are not filled";

        echo $error;
    }

    //insert data to the database

    if(isset($_POST["btnInsert"]))
    {   
        $insertString = "INSERT INTO library_comment VALUES('$regNumber', '$name', '$comment')";

        $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","iwt");

        if(!mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO library_comment VALUES('$regNumber', '$name', '$comment')"))
        {
            die('Error: '.mysqli_error($connection));
        }

        else
        {
            echo '<br/>';
            echo '1 record added...';
        }
    }

    //update data in the database

    else if(isset($_POST["btnUpdate"]))
    {           
        $query = "UPDATE library_comment SET regNumber = '$regNumber', name = '$name', comment = '$comment' WHERE regNumber = '$regNumber'";

        $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","iwt");

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if (!$result) 
        {
            die('Error: '.mysqli_error($connection));
        } 

        else 
        {           
            echo '<br/>';
            echo '1 record updated...';
        }
    }

    else if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
    {
        $updateString = "DELETE FROM library_comment WHERE regNo = '$regNumber'";

        $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","iwt");

        if(!mysqli_query($connection, $updateString))
        {
            die('Error: '.mysqli_error($connection));
        }

        else
        {
            echo '<br/>';
            echo '1 record deleted...';
        }
    }
?>

<hr/>

</h4>

<div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  .btn{
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <div align="center">
  <form name = "comments" method = "POST" action = "addComment.php">
   <table>
    <caption><b><h2>Comments on Library Service </h2></b></caption>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Registration Number</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="regNo" /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>Name with initials</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Kamal.P"/></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>Year :</td>
     <td>
     <input list="year" name="year" />
     <datalist id="year">
      <option value="Please choose">
      <option value="Year 1">
      <option value="Year 2">
      <option value="Year 3">
      <option value="Year 4">
     </datalist>
     </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>Faculty :</td>
     <td>
     <input list="faculty" name="faculty" />
     <datalist id="faculty">
      <option value="Please choose">
      <option value="Faculty of Computing">
      <option value="Faculty of Business">
      <option value="Faculty of Engineering">
     </datalist>
     </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td>Comments on the Service :</td>
     <td><textarea name="comment" row="5" cols="30"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    
    
    
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input class="btn" type="submit" name="btnInsert" value="Insert"/>
      <input class="btn" type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="Update"/>
      <input class="btn" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
     </td>

     <td>
      <input class="btn" type="button" name="btnView" value="View"/>
      <input class="btn" type="reset" name="btnReset" value="Reset"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking at your code, the first batch of `empty()` isnt checking anything as they're not within the `isset($_POST())`

Comment: Also your query is wide open to SQL Injections you shouldn't be adding `$variable` into the query, you should be binding params instead to prevent such a flaw.

Comment: try WHERE regNumber = $regNumber"; instead WHERE regNumber = '$regNumber'";

Comment: May I also add, you shouldn't be connecting numerous times to the database. You should make this a one-time connection within another file and then simply include it.

Comment: there is a comma before WHERE. Please remove it..thats make the error

Comment: Agree with @shashi , apart from all the bad practices you can always improve on, if your column `regNumber` stores integers, you can't insert strings, which is what you are doing by putting the variable between quotes.

Comment: Nobody else mentioning the fact of security flaws? :|

Comment: Removing quotation marks didn't solve the error. It still showing me the error :/ @AntoniuLivadariu, shashi

Comment: Take a look at what @next2u said, that is indeed causing a problem

Comment: I feel @next2u  is right.

Comment: (*What* use is `SET regNumber = '$regNumber', […] WHERE regNumber = '$regNumber'` ?) Drop the comma before `WHERE`. (And fix your first code block. Use (vertical) white space judiciously, esp. in SE code blocks.)

Comment: I've removed the comma. Now it's saying "Unknown Column "ITXXXX" :( I have 3 columns in the database, namely regNo, stdName, comment :( why it's not getting the value I enter in the field? @next2u

Comment: @ hashini.W, in your previous comment you said that the 3 columns  in the database are `regNo, stdName, comment`. But you are using in update query `regNumber , name , comment` respectively.

Comment: Yeah @next2u That one plus the comma before where were the errors :/ Stupid me! Anyways thanks a lot for helping me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've solved the problem. The problem was in the where clause which it should be corrected as "[....] WHERE regNo = '$regNumber'"

Comment: Again... Yes your problem may be fixed but the coding is of poor quality with security flaws. I hope this only on a localhost environment and not a live server otherwise you're opening yourself up to all kinds of problems.

Comment: I've just started learning PHP @Option. I Haven't done validation or that security part yet. I know there may be  a lot to improve, but i'm still a beginner. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: Given you have just started please allow me to suggest looking into learning PDO / OOP.